# Use ARM to setup App Service access using MSI

Tags: azure-resource-manager, azure-keyvault, azure-managed-identity

There are two properties listed in the key vault documentation:

- objectId  string  Yes The object ID of a user, service principal or security group in the Azure Active Directory tenant for the vault. The object ID must be unique for the list of access policies.
- applicationId string  No  Application ID of the client making request on behalf of a principal - globally unique identifier

Questions:

- Should I be using objectId for the MSI principalId?
- Is the concept of applicationId redudant when working with MSI. There's so much documentation on MSDN that I'm having a hard time figuring out which approach to take, and whether the concept of applicationId/secrets is redudant when using MSI.
- Is TenantId required?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should I be using objectId for the MSI principalId?

Yes, you should use MSI's object ID. You could get it with Power Shell. For example:

```
Get-AzureRmADServicePrincipal -SearchString "azure-cli-2017-04-13-02-33-36"\
```

Or get it on Azure Portal.

[image]

> Is the concept of applicationId redudant when working with MSI.
>   There's so much documentation on MSDN that I'm having a hard time
>   figuring out which approach to take, and whether the concept of
>   applicationId/secrets is redudant when using MSI.

When you create MSI, it will create a service principal, `applicationId` is sp's application id.

> Is TenantId required?

Yes, it is required.

Comment: See this document  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.keyvault/vaults